# Custom Shortcut Keys on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, python

Is there anyway I can change a shortcut key that an application has under one of it's menus in Ubuntu. For example I'm running `PyCrust` and want it to clear the window when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>L</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the gconf key `/desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels` to true will allow you to bind and unbind GTK+ menu items by hovering over the menu item and pressing the keystroke to bind, or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to unbind.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say how you might accomplish that.

PyShell is a shell - a character-based application - so it runs in a terminal emulator.  You don't say which terminal emulator you're using.  It might be possible to get the Ctrl-L behavior from the terminal emulator itself rather than from PyShell.

Note that's not how bash and tcsh implement ^L handling - they handle it themselves internally.

So I guess I'm saying you'd have to start hacking on pyshell itself to implement this, and that there's no "end user" way to hook that up.

Comment: Oops my bad. I meant `PyCrust`. This is a GUI based program.

Comment: So then I guess your best bet might be to ask over on http://www.wxpython.org/ how you might do this.  The source to pycrust is over there as well, so just dive in and take a look.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, there's nothing "infrastructure-wise" in Ubuntu (well, in the Xwindow system, actually) for generically supporting adding keystroke handlers and such.  It's done on an application by application basis.